# How to use decimal-format in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have incoming xml files where the number formats may differ depending on the locale of the creator.
I have found that `<xsl:decimal-format>` should take care of this, but haven't succeded.

Example of input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Network>
  <DataFrames>
      <DataFrame bitSize="11,111" name="Fiiil" offset="11.1112" period="11.1112" priority="0">
          <Path name="Fiiil-h28" parent="Fiiil">
              <Node name="h28" sequenceNumber="1" parent="Fiiil-h28"/>
          </Path>
      </DataFrame>
  </DataFrames>
</Network>
```

My xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0" >
<xsl:decimal-format decimal-separator="." grouping-separator=""/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<!-- Copy all nodes (that do not get a better match) unchanged -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DataFrame">
    <xsl:variable name="framename" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Path[@parent=$framename]">
            <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Path">
    <xsl:variable name="pathname" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='parent')]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Node[@parent=$pathname]">
            <xsl:sort select="@sequenceNumber" data-type="text" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have read that not assigning a name for the decimal-format will make it default. Having group-separator as an empty string causes a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, but even if I specify a character for the group-separator, the numeric attributes (bitsize, offset, period) are unaffected.

Comment: "*the number formats may differ depending on the locale of the creator.*" Do you have a way of finding out what the number format in use is? For example: is there a number that you know in advance to contain a decimal separator? -- Note also that your input example is confusing, as it uses different number formats for different nodes; surely that will not happen with your real input?

Comment: The example does not use different number formats for different nodes. It uses "," for separator and "." for decimal point (as I believe is standard in many countries).

Comment: So bitSize in your example is Eleven Thousands, One Hundred and One? -- You haven't answered my question. If your input can contain **both** "1.234" and "1,234" in the same document, and you don't have a way to determine which one is which (that is to find out which standard is being used by the document's author), then this problem has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in XSLT and XPath 1.0 in input documents are parsed as double precision floating point numbers http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers and the use of `xsl:decimal-format` does not have any influence on that as it is merely used to define formats for the use of output formatting with `format-number`.

So any approach to change number parsing with `xsl:decimal-format` is not going to work. I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, if you have number values not being in the cited number format and want to parse them as numbers you need to make sure you first convert them to the right format using string functions e.g. `translate('3,1415926', ',', '.')`.

The XSLT code you have posted does not parse any numbers and it does not format any. If you took out the `<xsl:decimal-format decimal-separator="." grouping-separator=""/>`, it would simply process the node values as strings. I am afraid "regardless of which number format the input has" is rather broad and vague, as I already said, for parsing values as numbers XSLT and XPath 1.0 only support the http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers format with no grouping separator, with a decimal point `.` as the decimal separator. Anything different cannot be parsed as a number unless converted first and within XSLT 1.0 you have only string functions like `translate` to do any conversions.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is output xml files that all use the same number format regardless of which number format the different input file has.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT has no facilities for parsing numbers that appear in the XML in localized formats. You will have to write such functions yourself. It will be a lot easier if you use XSLT 2.0 (where you could use regular expressions to translate the numbers into standard XSD format).

The general advice when you are using XML for data interchange between applications is to use standard (non-localized) formats for communicating between applications; localization should be done at the last possible moment before presentation to a human user. But that advice may come too late for you.